# Payment System And Method For Team Developer Game Unity

Tags: c#, in-app-purchase, unity-game-engine

I am developing a mobile android game now. And in the game player will be able to purchase an item from the game. But in developing the game we have a team that have only two people (me and the other one). I am the programmer and other is as designer.

Because of two people we need to make a payment method if Player purchase for example : Player purchase $100 than $50 for me and $50 for the other one. And if it is possible the payment will automatic link or send to each our bank account or e-bank account (something like save our money and it can be withdraw to our bank account for INTERNATIONAL).

Or maybe the income can be separetely more than two people ? Automatic of course.

What is the best one to choose the payment system ? Is it possible to do like the example ?

This is to prevent for member team to cheating each other. I think this is the safe way for earning from in app purchase.

If it is not possible what is the best way about the payment ?

Thanks

Dennis

Comment: try soomla. and also stop thinking like a developer, game dev is much more than that. have one shared bank account and let the bank decide on those matters not the plugin!

Comment: The best way to go about this is to have one account where payments are made and split evenly when you withdraw from it. One of you will need to manage that account though.

Comment: Hi @Bijan Hi MirceaDogaru Thanks for sharing.